# How to use array.items in joiful validation?

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, joi

```
 @jf.array().items()required()
```

I tried to array.items validation code using joyful. but I do no how to give items in joiful validation can you give some example code or link

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I read [joi array](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v8.0.5/API.md#array) and help full for me, you can use this pattern.its work

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    password: Joi.string().regex(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$/),
    access_token: [Joi.string(), Joi.number()],
    birthyear: Joi.number().integer().min(1900).max(2013),
    email: Joi.string().email({ minDomainAtoms: 2 })
}).with('username', 'birthyear').without('password', 'access_token');

// Return result.
var services = Joi.array().items(schema);
const result = Joi.validate([{ username: 'abc', birthyear: 1994 }, { username: 'abc', birthyear: 1994 }], services);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `items`:

```
@jf.array({ elementClass: ClassWithJoifulDecorators })
@jf.array({ elementClass: String })
```

With `items` (useless, you can use `elemetClass` syntax from above example)

```
@jf.array().items(joi => joi.object( SchemaYouCanReplaceWithAboveSyntax))
@jf.array().items(joi => joi.string())
```

The only required usage of `items` in joful:

```
@jf.array().items(joi => joi.valid(['list', 'of', 'exclusive' 'values']))
```

`Items` should be used in case of whitelisting array values because `valid` decorator is not working as expected:

```
// This will not work as expected
@jf.array().valid(['list', 'of', 'exclusive' 'values'])
```